Who was revolutionary?
Who Am I?
   ×••chi×••nh


It might look like enough info hasn't been given but all you need to know has been given. Google (if necessary) to be sure that your answer is correct.

You are:

 Ho Chi Minh, the Vietnamese Communist revolutionary.

Find this by...

 substituting the letters of the question - WHOAMI - into the gaps between the letters in the given string, but delete those corresponding to the cross symbols, i.e. the W and A, and keep only those that fill the gaps marked by dots:

 [w]hochi[a]minh

 The result is HOCHIMINH, i.e. Ho Chi Minh.


Yes :) Well done!

Nice. I actually knew Ho Chi Minh, who is now the namesake of what was Saigon, but not its connection with the puzzle.
